# Error when connecting to AS400 (ISeries)

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange, data-access

I'm trying to connect to a AS400 server using the .net classes.
I have added a reference to IBM.Data.DB.iSeries and I use the following code:
 var conn = new iDB2Connection("DataSource=111.111.111.111;UserID=xxx;Password=xxx; DataCompression=True;");
            conn.Open();

But I get the following exceptions
Running 64 bit: "The provider cannot run in 64-bit mode."
Running 32 bit: An unexpected exception occurred.  Type: System.DllNotFoundException, Message: Unable to load DLL 'cwbdc.dll': The operating system cannot run . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6).

I have uninstalled the Client Access and installed it again.
The cwbdc.dll does exist in the system32 and syswow64 .
I have no problem connecting to the AS400 if I use odbc.

I'm running a 64 bit verion of Windows 7.
Any ideas?

/Jimmy

Comment: +1 for helping me figure out my issue by asking first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the driver you are using is not supported on 64 bit systems. In the properties of your project in the Build tab try setting the Platform Target to `x86` instead of `Any CPU`.

Comment: When setting it to x86 I get the other errormessage: "An unexpected exception occurred. Type: System.DllNotFoundException, Message: Unable to load DLL 'cwbdc.dll': The operating system cannot run . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6)."

Comment: +1 - I was getting the same error, found your answer and it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar issue and replacing Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable with its [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) resolved it. (Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3412380/908336)