# How to debug manifest errors?

Tags: debugging, manifest

I am creating an application that depends on third-party library, which in turn depends on MSVCP90D.dll. While running the application it fails to start and provides an error message:

[image]

I have found such library in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT`. As you can see one of them is 64-bit, while the other is 32-bit. When I have placed 64-bit into the directory of the application the application silently crashes while loading (log from Visual Studio Output window is below). With the 32-bit one I get another error message:

[image]

If I press `Abort` -- programs shuts down, `Retry` results in breaking into debug session for `crt0msg.c` file. This is system file and I have no idea how to debug it. If I press Ignore I get yet another error message:

[image]

So the question is **how to debug such errors?** Please give me some links where I can read more about it or point me out what exactly I should do in such cases. I know this relates to manifest problems, therefore if you know any please give me a link to good resource which describes manifests in detail, since what I have found so far have only confused me.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.4108 QFE.

This is log for 64-bit version of the MSVCP90D.dll library:

```
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'D:\Projects\Chromium\devenv\install\build-msvc-debug\chromium-xml3d-rtsg2\chrome.exe', Symbols loaded.
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'D:\Projects\Chromium\devenv\install\build-msvc-debug\chromium-xml3d-rtsg2\chrome.dll', Symbols loaded.
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\comctl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'D:\Projects\Chromium\devenv\install\build-msvc-debug\rtsg2\bin\RTSG2.dll', Symbols loaded.
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'D:\Projects\Chromium\devenv\install\build-msvc-debug\chromium-xml3d-rtsg2\chrome.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'D:\Projects\Chromium\devenv\install\build-msvc-debug\rtsg2\bin\RTSG2.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\comctl32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'chrome.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The program '[1152] chrome.exe: Native' has exited with code 9 (0x9).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After studying some online resources I have found solution myself. So manifests have to be embedded into every application and dependent library that requires loading of some external library in turn. In my situation third-party library I was using didn't include such a manifest. I have manually included one and this solved the problem.

Tools that I have used for debugging this problem were [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) and some manuals online including other questions on StackOverflow:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235532(v=VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342(v=VS.80).aspx
- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375365.aspx
- [msvcr90d.dll not found in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150464/msvcr90d-dll-not-found-in-debug-mode)

Hope this will be useful for somebody.

---

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions)

Comment: Could it be that you can use one of the certification kits these days?