# msvcr90d.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msvcr90.dll

I know this question is being asked all over the places. But here is my problem. I tried to compile a program using wxWidgets with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. When I tried to run, it gives me the error,

```
"your program cant run because msvcr90d.dll is missing from your computer."
```

The thing is I have that file in 
`

> "**C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_96748342450f6aa2**"

folder as well as I have it in

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT"

folder as well. 
I was wondering why my program cannot find that file.
If anyone knows the reason, please help me how to fix this issue.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. I tried researching a lot but nothing showed up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `msvcr90d.dll` into `C:\Windows\System32`, then your issue will solve.

Comment: I did that, but it still gives me that message. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of [MSVCR90D.dll not found in debug mode with Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218747/msvcr90d-dll-not-found-in-debug-mode-with-visual-c-2008?rq=1), which does have a solution that works for me.

The solution that worked for me was to copy both `msvcr90d.dll` and `Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.manifest` to the same directory as the executable.

I got these files come from a machine that had Visual Studio 2008 installed from this directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\`